# How to register custom scope in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-swf

I'm trying to register a custom scope to incorporate a third party library, Amazon SWF. Specifically a 'workflow' scope.

I was wondering how you would do this in Spring Boot using annotations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring JavaConfig, bean's custom scopes and annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435860/spring-javaconfig-beans-custom-scopes-and-annotations)

Answer (score 2):

Similar question was asked here: [Spring JavaConfig, bean's custom scopes and annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435860/spring-javaconfig-beans-custom-scopes-and-annotations)

You need to create new annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Scope("workflow")
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WorkflowScoped {
}
```

And add it to your workflow scoped bean:

```
@Component
@WorkflowScoped 
public class WorkflowScopedBean {
```

Comment: You don't "need" to create a new annotation. You could also use `@Scope("workflow")` on your beans.