# A Java config analog of XML configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, jbehave, dynamic-proxy

TL/DR: The problem boils down to creating a custom Spring scope, injecting a `prototype`-like scoped bean into a singleton with `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` but still getting a singleton in the Java config version of the configuration (whereas it works fine with XML).

**UPDATE:** Problem solved, see answer.

---

I'm using jBehave to write BDD test scenarios for our Spring application. We recently thought that we need independence in executing test scenarios (meaning that test context has to be reset before each scenario) and found [this](https://edgblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/scoping-jbehave-tests-with-spring/) article on the web that addresses exactly the issue we're dealing with.

The article advises creating a custom Spring `Scenario` scope, assigning it to the class that represents test context and injecting an AOP proxy instead of the context file.

I've coded everything in accordance with the article and it worked great, but the thing is we need it in terms of Java config, not XML, and when I converted all the changes to Java config, it stopped working - meaning the `Map` in `StoryContext` was not reset after each test scenario and contained values from the previous scenario.

My changes were as follows:

- marked the `ScenarioScope` class with the `@Component` annotation:

```
@Component
public class ScenarioScope implements Scope {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @BeforeScenario
    public void startScenario() {
        cache.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        return cache.putIfAbsent(name, objectFactory.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(String name) {
        return cache.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return "scenario scope";
    }
}
```

- created a Spring configuration class to add the new scope:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer scopeConfigurer() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        configurer.addScope("scenario", new ScenarioScope());
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

- annotated the `StoryContext` class with the `@Component` and `@Scope` annotations:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "scenario", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class StoryContext {

  private Map<String, Object> storyContext = new HashMap<>();

  public void put(String key, Object value) {
    storyContext.put(key,value);
  }

  public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> tClass) {
    return (T) storyContext.get(key);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void clearContext() {
    storyContext.clear();
  }
}
```

To my knowledge, the code above is analogous to the XML configuration, which was as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo"/>

    <bean id="scenarioScope" class="foo.ScenarioScope"/>

    <bean class="foo.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="scenario" value-ref="scenarioScope"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="storyContext" class="foo.StoryContext" scope="scenario">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can anyone please point me to why the Java config is not working as expected? I've spent some time researching stackoverflow but the majority of similar questions is solved by adding `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` to the `@Scope` annotation, which I did.

**UPDATE:** So I tried to gradually move from XML to Java config by commenting / decommenting corresponding lines in the files and figured out that the problem is in this part of the code:

```
    <bean class="foo.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="scenario" value-ref="scenarioScope"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I replace it with

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer scopeConfigurer() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        configurer.addScope("scenario", new ScenarioScope());
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

the `StoryContext` bean becomes a singleton. I tried doing it another way through registering a custom `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and using the `registerScope()` method as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-scope), but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem, and the solution was trivial: the `ScenarioScope` instance in the `SpringConfiguration` class has to be managed by the Spring container rather than be created via the `new()` operator:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer scopeConfigurer(ScenarioScope scenarioScope) {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        configurer.addScope("scenario", scenarioScope);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can accept your own answer in order to close the question.

Comment: @kriegaex, sure, just three more hours of waiting before I'm allowed to. :)