# How do I convert an applicationContext.xml into a spring @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this `applicationContext.xml` file, which I want to express as a spring `@Configuration` component. How can I do that? Is there a section in the official spring docs about how to convert XML configurations into Java-based configuration?

Following XML snippet is from [this](https://github.com/jneat/spring-jsf) project which implements a custom ViewScope for Spring. In order to use its ViewScope implementation I have to add this configuration in to my `applicationContext.xml`, But I want to express this configuration in Java.

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="view">
                <bean class="com.github.jneat.jsf.ViewScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (was in readme of project that you [pointed](https://github.com/jneat/spring-jsf/blob/master/README.md)):

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.github.jneat.jsf.ViewScope;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyViewScope {

    @Bean
    public CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();

        Map<String,Object> scopes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        scope.put("view", new ViewScope());

        configurer.setScopes(scopes);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

You can also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15435860/11733759)

Comment: This code is confusing to me... how come the `InitViewScope` doesn't have a return type, Is it the constructor (with a typo)?

Comment: Yes there was a bug (i just copied and pasted it from that repo) . Try current version.

Comment: Thanks for 'accepted' if the answer is helpful you can also 'voted up' it @k-var

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Bean
public CustomScopeConfigurer customScope(WorkflowScope viewScope) {
    CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
    Map<String, Object> viewScope = new HashMap<>();

    viewScopeSet.put("view", viewScope);
    configurer.setScopes(viewScopeSet);

    return configurer;
}
```

Comment: As `CustomScopeConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` it should be a `public static` method not just a `public` method. This is due the the bean being needed very early in the proces.